# Large data aggregations good in Business Layer(JAVA) or DatabaseLayer(Stored Procedures)?

Tags: java, architecture, database-performance, n-tier-architecture

In our application we have very large data.
We would require to do aggregations and calculations for various conditions(based on what user select in UI).

1)Since the data is very large is it advised to do all the
    aggregations(business logic) in database(procedures) ?or
  2)Will there be a major impact if done in Business Layer after getting    data from DB? 
     As  all the data will be converted to objects and then aggregation is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your app/web server and your database server are separated. You will want to minimize the amount of data that needs to cross the wire. Besides, data aggregation is something database engines are very good at so you should let them do what they do well. So I'd suggest you do the aggregation in your database.

Comment: Yes,app server and database server are separated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you should use the database to do most of the work, but you can use ad hoc queries driven by the business logic rather than stored procedures.